# Android java - how to make Activity wait until Service is binded?

Tags: java, android, service, binding

Every example has Service bind onStart() and calling method from a Service in a while (like after onClick). Until that onClick service is being binded for sure.

I got problem that service is taking a while until it's binded and it binds asynchronously.
So if I start and Activity which needs to get some data from a Service right away - it crashes because it's not yet binded. So I need to hold my Activity waiting until it's connection finishes. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want that: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html.

On this page you can find:

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

The `onServiceConnected` method is called when the service is ready and you can do your stuff inside (or use the mBound attribute).

To bind to your service, use that:

```
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: yeah, I know that. but if you try to do something like localService.myMethod(); - your activity will crash because binding is not going to be immediatly and if you ask if mBound true or false - it's for sure will be false. What I need is some kind of listener when mBound will be true so Activity can go on

Comment: You can then put your code directly in `onServiceConnected`. What's the problem with that ?

Comment: Great! now that's the answer I was looking for !) I just moved all Activity there

Comment: well I accepted that, but answer was not on my question . My question was about how to make activity wait for bound

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage a pendingList variable to handle this situation:

```
private ICoreService mService;
private boolean mConnected = false;
private boolean mConnecting = false;
private List<Something> mPendingTasks = new ArrayList<Something>;

private void bindService() {     
        try {
            Intent service = new Intent();
            service.setClassName(Constants.THE_SERVICE_PACKAGE_NAME, Constants.THE_SERVICE_FULL_NAME);
            mContext.bindService(service, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            mConnecting = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
              //handle exception
        }        
}

public void serviceDoSomething(Something task) {
    try {
        if (mService == null) {
            synchronized (mPendingTasks) {
                mPendingTasks.add(task);
            }
        } else {
            mService.doSomething(task);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       //handle exception
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mConnected = false;
        mConnecting = false;
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mConnected = true;
        mConnecting = false;
        mService = ICoreService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        drainPendingTasks();
    }
};

private void drainPendingTasks() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (mPendingTasks) {
                try {
                    if (!mPendingTasks.isEmpty()) {
                        for (Something task : mPendingTasks) {
                            mService.doSomething(task);
                        }
                        mPendingTasks.clear();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```